# Issue with strange user control stretching in VS Designer

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, user-controls

I have been working on a freelance project for a couple of days and two of my user controls started to stretch in size within the designer. It doesn't seem to have an effect when compiled, but it makes it impossible to design the forms when everything is stretched out.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGRn2.png

Whenever I reset the size in the properties, it just snaps back to what it currently is.

I've tried resetting the size and restoring Visual Studio back to default settings.

The WinForm should be 806,649 in the designer so I can continue to design the forms.

Comment: Do you have some layout logic in those UserControls? Have you tried to set the `AutoscaleMode` to `DPI` or `None`?

Comment: Not that I remember changing but I can go back and try to look at those settings. I just find it weird that they were fine one second then blown out of proportion a second later and only in the Designer.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather confusing. You mention two user controls, but I see only one in your image. You say: "I reset the size in the properties, it just snaps back to what it currently is"--to what does "it" refer? Is it the user control or the form? "The WinForm should be 806,649 in the designer", it is unclear what WinForm you're referring to--and why you cannot resize it. When you say "it" doesn't have an effect when compiled, do you mean that everything looks good when running a compiled version of the project?

Let's start with basics: If you open each of your user controls independently into a designer, does each user control appear the way you want? Or are you having problems only when you place the user control on a form in design mode?

What are the two user controls you're referring to? Are you saying that each user control has a sizing issue?

Can you show a screenshot not of the user control's property grid, but of the parent form's property grid?